# Theme mobile optimization and upgrade suggestions

Tags: theming, javascript

I am running a medium trafficked Drupal 6 site with some custom modules, theme and a few thousand nodes. Our major woe is optimizing the site for different media displays or just responsify the current custom theme, and perhaps upgrade to Drupal 7 along the way.

What do you suggest about the following pathways?

1. Should I not worry about upgrading to Drupal 7, create a seperate jQuery mobile site and separate the mobile traffic to m.domain.com using domain module? It is very challenging to make themes responsive in Drupal 6.
2. Upgrade to Drupal 7, recode the theme to be responsive. But by the finish line, Drupal 8 would have matured enough. Should I even bother to upgrade to Drupal 7?
3. Wait for Drupal 8 release

Which one would you choose and why? Or any other optimal suggestions?

Cheers 
[raises a pint of IPA]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mobile developing for D6 shouldn't be any harder than for D7.
Actually, i remember that when i was building my last responsive website, there were a few useful modules only available for D6.

D8 much probably won't be out before 2014, and after the official release, it's going to take many months before all the themes and modules will get ported... many people may not be able to use D8 until 2015 or so. Probably.

It will be indeed much more mobile friendly, so it might be well worth the effort of porting.

But I don't really see the need to port to D7 at the moment.

Whether to make a separate site on a subdomain or a single responsive site is a very subjective question. Anyway, mobile_tools will probably have everything you need for both scenarios: https://drupal.org/project/mobile_tools